# Product model not returning description

Tags: magento, model, product

Which reasons can it have, when a product model is not returning the description attribute?

I tested several approaches:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'P001')->getData();
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'P001')->getData('description');
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'P001')->getDescription();
```

The getData() method returns even the short_description, but not the description.
I think it can't be a code fault, because in my **local environment**, it's working. Via git, I have the **same codebase** also on my **stage server**, where it's not working anymore.

Can somebody have edited some attribute settings to cause that problem? (I couldn't find any differences between short_description and description which could cause that problem in my opinion.

EDIT: On the stage page, descriptions are shown in articles.

Comment: Goto Manage Attributes in the admin and ensure that the attribute is set to YES for "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" (assuming you're in a frontend context)

Answer (score 0):

To get the product details by loading sku, use the below code

```
<?php
$product_sku = "P001";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadBySku($product_sku);
echo $product->getDescription();
?>
```